# Spring Integration AMQP ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

We're using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to parallelize the execution of a message handler, but we're running into concurrent modification exception.

Below is the exception that is thrown:

```
2018-07-26 21:18:15.563 ERROR [dia-feed-sftp,a889a5984eb10d70,3a486897c53ed430,false] 7643 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@2f91c88]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[3445], headers={auditId=e6af7733-455b-490b-8acd-319c57f3ef5e, file_remoteDirectory=/usr/appl/dia/data/wrk/pcf_test_dev/e2e_debug_1/, X-B3-ParentSpanId=b31063e9685ce603, scst_partition=0, closeableResource=org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession@2f64d8bc, file_remoteFile=BROBRG.D203, spanTraceId=a889a5984eb10d70, spanId=928797df743c4c03, spanParentSpanId=b31063e9685ce603, file_remoteFileInfo={"directory":false,"filename":"BROBRG.D203","link":false,"modified":1532374864000,"permissions":"-rwxr-x---","remoteDirectory":"/usr/appl/dia/data/wrk/pcf_test_dev/e2e_debug_1/","size":20136538}, nativeHeaders={X-B3-ParentSpanId=[a6012ccb232fd522], X-B3-Sampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[a889a5984eb10d70], X-B3-TraceId=[a889a5984eb10d70]}, partitionKey=M65Y26Z, X-B3-SpanId=928797df743c4c03, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=a889a5984eb10d70, id=75e29c84-f80f-fbf7-1fb8-82dbdb836c1e, spanSampled=0, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1532639895536}]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:725)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:278)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:379)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:373)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1847)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1784)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:864)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:719)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:752)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:750)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.convertHeaderValueIfNecessary(DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.convertHeadersIfNecessary(DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.fromMessageProperties(DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.sendToRabbit(RabbitTemplate.java:2010)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1999)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.lambda$send$3(RabbitTemplate.java:865)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1841)
    ... 122 more
```

Below is our configuration:

```
@Qualifier("auditChannel")
@Bean
public MessageChannel auditChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(threadPoolTaskExecutor()).get();
}



@Bean
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow auditIntegrationFlow(
    OperationalDataStoreClient operationalDataStoreClient,
    @Qualifier("auditChannel") MessageChannel auditChannel,
    Clock clock
) {
    return from(auditChannel)
        .filter(message -> !(message instanceof FileSplitter.FileMarker))
        .handle(new FileAuditHandler(operationalDataStoreClient, clock))
        .get();
}


public class FileAuditHandler {

public void transform(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MessageHeaders messageHeaders = message.getHeaders();
    String fileName = (String) messageHeaders.get("file_remoteFile");

    FileAuditRecord fileAuditRecord = new FileAuditRecord(
            fileName,
        LocalDateTime.ofInstant(clock.instant(), ZoneId.of("UTC")));

    try {
        operationalDataStoreClient.write("/ods/fms/file_audit/" + messageHeaders.get("auditId") + ".json",
            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(fileAuditRecord),
            "ods_fms_file_audit");

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Could it be because of the way ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is being used or the fileAuditHandler is wired incorrectly?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **full** stack trace (not an edited one).

Comment: Question updated with complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This implies that you have a message header that is of type `Map<?, ?>` and you have that same header value in multiple messages, or you are somehow modifying that map while it is being examined for inclusion in the outgoing message...

```
else if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> originalMap = (Map<String, Object>) value;
    Map<String, Object> writableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(originalMap.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : originalMap.entrySet()) {
        writableMap.put(entry.getKey(), this.convertHeaderValueIfNecessary(entry.getValue()));
    }
    value = writableMap;
}
```

The converter is iterating over the map while some other thread is modifying that map.

If you have a `Map<?, ?>` value in a header, it needs to be unique and not modified.

You can use something like...

```
setHeader("myMapHeader", new HashMap<>(sourceMap))
```

...or make the map a `ConcurrentMap` which allows one thread to iterate while another is modifying it.

However, it is suspicious because you would have a race condition as to whether the iterator will see the changes or not.

While the framework ensures that messages and message headers are immutable, if you add mutable objects to the payload and/or headers, there is nothing the framework can do to protect from this kind of problem.

Comment: Gary, thank you for your response. The only Map headers we see in the message are added by Spring Integration: 
`file_remoteFileInfo=
  {
    "directory": false,
    "filename": "REDACTED.D203",
    "link": false,
    "modified": 1532374864000,
    "permissions": "-rwxr-x---",
    "remoteDirectory": "redacted",
    "size": 20136538
  },
  nativeHeaders=
  {
    X-B3-ParentSpanId=
  [
    a6012ccb232fd522
  ],
  X-B3-Sampled=
  [
    0
  ],
  X-B3-TraceId=
  [
    a889a5984eb10d70
  ],
  X-B3-TraceId=
  [
    a889a5984eb10d70
  ]
  } ` Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe `file_remoteFileInfo` is a simple JSON string not a `Map`. `nativeHeaders` looks like sleuth. I am not familiar with its internals but it's likely that is the smoking gun. You could try adding a header enricher upstream to replace the `nativeHeaders` header with a private copy. `.enrichHeaders(...)` be sure to set the `overwrite` so the shared map is replaced with the private one. It will only work if the header is present upstream of the adapter. If not, you should probably open an issue against [spring-cloud-sleuth](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth).

Comment: I just looked at the stealth code and it does update an existing map, if present. Since you have a splitter you have a copy of that map in every split so replacing the header with a private copy before the adapter should solve the issue - `headers.put("nativeHeaders", new HashMap<>(headers.get("nativeHeaders"))`.

Comment: It needs to be a new `LinkedMultiValueMap<>()` But, I would raise an issue against sleuth; they can't assume the header is not present in multiple messages, e.g. after a split.